# SQL clone records and make sure that fields match new ids

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to write an `SQL script` to clone my record and since there are some relation, want to update the fields that have relations with other fields in order to assure that columns point to the newly records id.

`Teachers` can have assigned `students` or another `teachers` to them, as well as `students` can have assigned `teachers` to them or another `students`.

Example:

Data in DB before any cloning:

```
Teacher 1 (id = 100, teacher_id = NULL, student_id = NULL)
Teacher 2 (id = 101, teacher_id = 100, student_id = NULL)
Student 1 (id = 100, teacher_id = 100, student_id = NULL)
Student 2 (id = 101, teacher_id = NULL, student_id = 100)
```

New cloned records:

```
Teacher 1-CLONE (id = 102, teacher_id = NULL, student_id = NULL)
Teacher 2-CLONE (id = 103, teacher_id = 102, student_id = NULL)
Student 1-CLONE (id = 102, teacher_id = 102, student_id = NULL)
Student 2-CLONE (id = 103, teacher_id = NULL, student_id = 102)
```

And the full DB table will contain:

```
Teacher 1 (id = 100, teacher_id = NULL, student_id = NULL)
Teacher 2 (id = 101, teacher_id = 100, student_id = NULL)
Teacher 1-CLONE (id = 102, teacher_id = NULL, student_id = NULL)
Teacher 2-CLONE (id = 103, teacher_id = 102, student_id = NULL)
Student 1 (id = 100, teacher_id = 100, student_id = NULL)
Student 2 (id = 101, teacher_id = NULL, student_id = 100) 
Student 1-CLONE (id = 102, teacher_id = 102, student_id = NULL)
Student 2-CLONE (id = 103, teacher_id = NULL, student_id = 102)
```

Any solutions or guides in order to succeed?

Comment: If  you  are going to clone the row,  the clone the complete row including the id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, if the IDs are consecutive:

```
DECLARE @C INT;
SET @C = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T);

INSERT INTO T (…) 
SELECT id+@C, teacher_id+@C, student_id+@C, … 
FROM T
```

If the IDs are not consecutive, you can determine @C in another way, to avoid overlapping, but the idea is the same.